# Create Custom JellyBean ROM in android mobile

Tags: android, sony

I have Sony xperia Sola . The thing is that with sony hasnt released Ice cream Sandwich Upgrade and now Google has developed Jelly Bean ROM .
         SO i want to create my Custom Jelly Bean ROM for my Mobile . I want to Know how to do ? becaues SOny might be using different chips in its mobile so what to do about that ??

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com Will be good resource for You.
To build for the device you can visit the links mentioned below http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_new_device.html I think This is enough to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is a popular custom rom [cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/)

Comment: but i want Jelly bean not ICS

Comment: for my mobile model MT27i  cynogen has no ROM

Comment: i want to make Custom ROM, how do i ?